# merging all csv files into one big csv file per folder using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a directory with multiple sub-directories and sub-sub-directories.
My goal is to read all the csv files and append them into one big csv file per sub-directory (P.S. not one big csv file per sub-sub-directory but one file per sub-directory).

The following is the code I have been using to append all the csv files into 1 big csv file but the only issue with this code is that **the final csv file turns out to be around ~890 MB which makes it unreadable when you try opening the file in Microsoft Excel as it runs into "memory issue".**

```py
dirName = 'FTP_Data/2019/'

allFilesList = list()
print('[info.] looking for .csv files.')
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
    for file in filenames:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            allFilesList += [os.path.join(dirpath, file).replace('\\','/')]

print('[info.] combining all the .csv files.')
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, sort=True) for file in allFilesList])
print('[info.] exporitng to one final output file.')
combined_csv.to_csv('FinalOutputFrom2019.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

the above code generates one big csv file called "FinalOutputFrom2019.csv".

Now if the directory is structured in the following manner, I want it to generate 12 files per month - `2019-01.csv`,`2019-02.csv`,`2019-03.csv`,`2019-04.csv`,`2019-05.csv`,`2019-06.csv`,`2019-07.csv`,`2019-08.csv`,`2019-09.csv`,`2019-10.csv`,`2019-11.csv`,`2019-12.csv`

```
FTP_data
|-- 2019
    |-- 2019-01
        |-- 2019-01-01
            |-- foo.csv
            |-- bar.csv
            |-- foobar.xml
        |-- 2019-01-03
            |-- foobar.csv
        |-- ...
    |-- 2019-02
        |-- 2019-02-02
            |-- ...
        |-- 2019-02-03
            |-- ...
        |-- 2019-02-05
            |-- ...
    |-- ...
```

Comment: What is the difficulty you encountered in looping through `2019-01` to `2019-12`?

Comment: @BillHuang no difficulty as such. The final file that gets created is just so BIG that it becomes impractical to open it in Microsoft Excel. It runs into "memory issues" as the final file is about 800+ MB in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adapt your working snippet to a for-loop through all months. Try this:

**Setup**

```
yr = 2019
dirName = f'FTP_Data/{yr}/'

def export_csv(dirName, csv_name):
    allFilesList = list()
    print('[info.] looking for .csv files.')
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dirName):
        for file in filenames:
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                allFilesList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file).replace('\\', '/'))

    print('[info.] combining all the .csv files.')
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, sort=True) for file in allFilesList])
    print('[info.] exporting to one final output file.')
    combined_csv.to_csv(f'{csv_name}.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

**Execute**

```
for mon in range(1, 13):
    # yr = dirName.split("/")[1]
    csv_name = f"{yr}-{mon:02}"
    subdirName = f"{dirName}{csv_name}"
    export_csv(subdirName, csv_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd


dirName = 'FTP_Data/2019/2019-'
Months = ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06','07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12')
# months are hard coded but if you prefer you can loop too.

Monthly_dirNames = []
i = 0
for mn in Months:
    path = dirName+mn

    #Get the list of csv files in each Sub directory:
    Monthly_Csv_Files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

    #*Optional* Show the csv files to be merged to the user
    print(f'CSV files for month_{mn} are :', Monthly_Csv_Files)

    # Read and concat all csv files in that sub directory to a Data Frame:
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path+'/'+file) for file in Monthly_Csv_Files])

    # Write Combined Data Frame as a csv file in that subfolder:
    # Removing 'path+' from below will write all csv files to .py's directory:
    combined_csv.to_csv(path+f'/Monthly_Output_From_2019_{mn}.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    i += 1
```

Comment: @aman-singh in my above code I didnt add `sort=True` to  `pd.read_csv(file, sort=True)` , it seems to be `sort=True` belongs to pd.concat not pd.read_csv method .Are you sure in your first code you dont get an argument error  too ?